# Function before form or form before function?

Tags: coding-style

What do you believe in? As an incomplete basis for a good product - would you prefer a mess of code that is horrible to look at but works perfectly for what its supposed to do, or a beautiful set of well organized classes (or something else if OO doesn't float your boat) but have buggy functionality that still needs a lot of work?

If you were just handed a project to improve and work towards completion, which would you prefer? And what do you put the emphasis on when starting a new project?

Comment: At a minimum, this should be community wiki.

Comment: form should follow function :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well written code will be easier to debug.  If the code is too messy, even if it has "no bugs" (unlikely) it will not be maintainable.

Comment: I've chosen this as the answer, because I have to choose something and its a good answer - though I could have gone with Pace's answer as well. I up voted both just to be on the safe side :-)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer both.  However, if I was going to be handed a project I would go with buggy but beautiful everytime.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about abstractions, I'd prefer to have just a small base set of working features. While it might be nice to have a pre-built, working library on top of this, the user can always create greater functionality from that working base.

Maybe they don't look nice, but again, a user can always just create a wrapper to make things look nice. I vote function.

Answer (score 0):

[**Real artists ship**](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RealArtistsShip) - so something, that is both beautiful and gets the job done. But when in doubt, err on the "gets the job done" side, even if it isn't perfection.